# Kotlin thinks that two methods have the same JVM signature, but the actually don't

Tags: kotlin

I came from the C# background and I know how to implement this in C#, but I'm struggling with Kotlin.
I've got 2 extension functions:

```
fun <T> Foo<T>.myFunction(func: () -> Unit): Foo<T>
```

and

```
fun <T> Foo<T>.myFunction(func: () -> Foo<T>): Foo<T>
```

Clearly, the return type of func is different in both functions. The first function executes it and returns this, the second executes func and returns the result of func.
But it gives me an error:

"Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature".

How to implement this correctly in Kotlin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the JVM, we have to [contend with type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699/49746). Meaning essentially that the types (`T` in this case) are thrown away in the compiled bytecode and that required checks are only done at compile time. Given that, you have to look at your function declaration with that in mind.

Kotlin will define your function argument as a `Function0` in both cases. Because the types are erased, `() -> Unit` and `() -> Foo<T>` both look the same in the bytecode. We can prove this out by decompiling the code you've provided (I renamed one of these `myFunction2` to get this to work):

```
public final class com/ginsberg/KotlinStuffKt {
    public final static myFunction(Lcom/ginsberg/Foo;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)Lcom/ginsberg/Foo;

    public final static myFunction2(Lcom/ginsberg/Foo;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)Lcom/ginsberg/Foo;

}
```

This is what the Kotlin compiler is generating (it does more, but I have removed the non-essential parts from this example). As you can see, our types are gone thanks to type erasure. And if we undo my change (`myFunction2` becomes `myFunction`), there's no way at all to tell these apart. This is what the compiler is complaining about - if you erase the types the JVM can't tell these functions apart.

Comment: Thank you, good answer! I'll try to also use the Function<out R> for an overload to avoid renaming my method..

Comment: Would the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579828/i-have-two-kotlin-extension-methods-for-the-same-class-but-with-a-different-gen also work there? Since extensions functions are resolved statically and the function shape is known at compile time, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Hay thanks, the methods now compile, but when I call them, it gives the following error:

"Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference:

atJvmName public fun <T> Foo<Any>.onSuccess(func: () → Foo<Any>): Foo<Any> defined in common.result

atJvmName public fun <T> Foo<Any>.onSuccess(func: () → Unit): Foo<Any> defined in common.result"

Comment: This answer doesn't tell you how to do it, it just identifies the problem.

Answer (score 19):

Your functions have a conflicting signature within the JVM due to type erasure (*the internal* `Function0<T>` *class being used to represent the function parameters*); and you can fix this by giving each of them a JVM specific name.  From Kotlin you would still access them by the original name, but from Java or internally another name is actually used.  Simply use the `@JvmName` annotation on the alternative versions:

```kotlin
fun <T> Foo<T>.myFunction(func: () -> Unit): Foo<T>

@JvmName("myfunctionWithFoo")   
fun <T> Foo<T>.myFunction(func: () -> Foo<T>): Foo<T>
```

Comment: I cannot access them from Kotlin, it gives me an error, I asked another question and the answer is there (it's not possible to access them) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581179/jvmname-for-overloads-makes-code-to-compile-but-when-calling-the-functions-an-e?noredirect=1#comment90128671_51581477

Comment: It is possible to access them @alex as mentioned in the other question, but this answer here is the correct answer to this specific question.  The issue with your lambdas inferring their type at the same time the compiler is trying to disambiguate functions is a different issue; and a separate answer is given there for that problem.  So for the error you have here, this is the correct answer.  For others reading this with similar problems, they may not encounter the second issue because the method signatures might be more specific without the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please change your fragmentManager name because your parameter as fragmentManager it will reversal with the base class parameter name which is also fragmentManager by default. So changing the name of your parameter will help you.

   ```
   from: 
    private val fragmentManager: FragmentManager? = null
    private val context: Context? = null

   to:
    private val fragmentManagerNowPlaying: FragmentManager? = null
    private val contextNowPlaying: Context? = null
   ```