# Can't create secondary constructors in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor, jvm

I was trying to create a class

```
class TestingModel {

    companion object {
        const val IMAGE_SLIDER: Int = 0
        const val TRENDING_ADS: Int = 1
    }

    var viewType: Int? = 0
    var imageSliderList: List<SlideModel>? = null
    var adsList: List<HomeTrendingAdsModel>? = null
    var categoryList: List<HomeCategoryModel>? = null



    constructor(viewType: Int?, imageSliderList: List<SlideModel>? = null) {
        this.viewType = viewType
        this.imageSliderList = imageSliderList
    }

    constructor(viewType: Int?, adsList: List<HomeTrendingAdsModel>?) {
        this.viewType = viewType
        this.adsList = adsList
    }

    constructor(viewType: Int?, categoryList: List<HomeCategoryModel>?) {
        this.viewType = viewType
        this.categoryList = categoryList
    }
}
```

However, I got an error saying

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature ( (Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/util/List;)V): 
public constructor TestingModel(viewType: Int?, imageSliderList: List<SlideModel>? = ...) defined in com.example.theads.Model.TestingModel
public constructor TestingModel(viewType: Int?, categoryList: List<HomeCategoryModel>?) defined in com.example.theads.Model.TestingModel
public constructor TestingModel(viewType: Int?, adsList: List<HomeTrendingAdsModel>?) defined in com.example.theads.Model.TestingModel
```

I saw in a library doing exactly the same without error.

Edit:
That other library is below:

```
class SlideModel {

    var imageUrl: String? = null
    var imagePath: Int? = 0
    var title: String? = null
    var scaleType: ScaleTypes? = null

    constructor(imageUrl: String?, title: String? = null, scaleType: ScaleTypes?  = null) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl
        this.title = title
        this.scaleType = scaleType
    }

    constructor(imagePath: Int?, title: String?  = null, scaleType: ScaleTypes?  = null) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath
        this.title = title
        this.scaleType = scaleType
    }

    constructor(imageUrl: String?, scaleType: ScaleTypes?) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl
        this.scaleType = scaleType
    }

    constructor(imagePath: Int?, scaleType: ScaleTypes?) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath
        this.scaleType = scaleType
    }
}
```

I'm creating a recycler view with multiple recyclerviews in it. So this class becomes a model class for that recyclerview and I want it to call viewType and differnet list from other model classes.
Thank you

Comment: I bet the library wasn't doing _exactly_ the same…  And I suspect that [this question](/questions/56646982/kotlin-declaration-signature-clash) covers it.

Comment: Hi there. Please can you update your question to use [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)? You can also see an explanation in the Kotlin documentation: [Handling signature clashes with @JvmName](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname)

Comment: Duplicate of [Kotlin thinks that two methods have the same JVM signature, but the actually don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580168/kotlin-thinks-that-two-methods-have-the-same-jvm-signature-but-the-actually-don)

Answer (score 1):

The example you provide, `class SlideModel`, has multiple constructors. Each constructor has a unique combination of parameter **types**. That's important - because Kotlin gets turned into Java, and in Java, the *names* of the parameters get ignored. The JVM compiler just doesn't care about the names - all it cares about is the order of the parameter **types**.

#### Conflicting constructors

Let's have a look at a simpler example (which I'll re-use for the rest of this answer, as I'm missing classes so I can't compile your code).

`class Example` has two constructors, each accepting a `String?` parameter. But it doesn't compile...

```kotlin
class Example {

  private var id: String? = null
  private var name: String? = null

  constructor(id: String?) {
    this.id = id
  }

  // ERROR
  // Conflicting overloads: 
  // public constructor Example(id: String?) defined in Example, 
  // public constructor Example(name: String?) defined in Example
  constructor(name: String?) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

This is a different error to the one you're seeing.

Unlike the constructors in `class SlideModel`, the constructors in `class Example` are not unique. The names of the parameters are ignored, and so all the compiler sees is two identical constructors - which is forbidden.

#### Conflicting generic constructors

Furthermore, because of type erasure, the JVM compiler can't distinguish based on generic types. For example, `List<String>` and `List<Int>` look the same after compilation, so again, you can't have two constructors that appear the same.

```kotlin
class ExampleLists {

  private var ids: List<Int>? = null
  private var names: List<String>? = null

  constructor(ids: List<Int>) {
    this.ids = ids
  }

  // ERROR
  // Platform declaration clash: 
  // The following declarations have the same JVM signature (<init>(Ljava/util/List;)V):
  //    constructor ExampleLists(ids: List<Int>) defined in ExampleLists
  //    constructor ExampleLists(names: List<String>) defined in ExampleLists
  constructor(names: List<String>) {
    this.names = names
  }
}
```

This is the same error you're seeing.

As @Zoe noted, this behaviour has been answered here: [Kotlin thinks that two methods have the same JVM signature, but the actually don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51580168/4161471)

#### Solutions

##### `@JvmName` & static method constructors

Because it's a constructor, you can't directly use the `@JvmName` annotation to help.

```kotlin
  // ERROR
  // This annotation is not applicable to target 'constructor'
  @JvmName("idConstructors") 
  constructor(ids: List<Int>) {
    this.ids = ids
  }
```

You can, however, create some functions that act like constructors, faux constructors, in a companion object.

```kotlin
// The 'faux constructors' must be imported
import ExampleLists.Companion.ExampleLists


class ExampleLists {

  private var ids: List<Int>? = null
  private var names: List<String>? = null

  companion object {

    /** Faux constructor - creates [ExampleLists] and sets [ExampleLists.ids] */
    @JvmName("exampleListsIds") // manually set JvmName, so each 'constructor' doesn't clash
    fun ExampleLists(ids: List<Int>): ExampleLists {
      val instance = ExampleLists()
      instance.ids = ids // only set ids
      return instance
    }

    /** Faux constructor - creates [ExampleLists] and sets [ExampleLists.names] */
    @JvmName("exampleListsNames") // manually set JvmName
    fun ExampleLists(names: List<String>): ExampleLists {
      val instance = ExampleLists()
      instance.names = names // only set names
      return instance
    }
  }

  override fun toString() = "ExampleLists(ids=$ids, names=$names)"

}

fun main() {
  println(ExampleLists(listOf("test"))) 
  // prints: ExampleLists(ids=[], names=[test])
  println(ExampleLists(listOf(1)))
  // prints: ExampleLists(ids=[1], names=[])
}
```

However I don't think this is great. It's so much code! It's clunky and difficult to scale and adapt.

##### A single constructor with defaults

Because Kotlin has overloads and default parameters, and your fields are defaulting to null in this instance, I suggest you only need one (default) constructor.

```
class ExampleLists(
  private var ids: List<Int>? = null,
  private var names: List<String>? = null,
) {
  override fun toString() = "ExampleLists(ids=$ids, names=$names)"
}


fun main() {
  println(ExampleLists(names = listOf("test")))
  // prints: ExampleLists(ids=[], names=[test])
  println(ExampleLists(ids = listOf(1)))
  // prints: ExampleLists(ids=[1], names=[])
}
```

Much better - smaller, compact, clearer, and utilises great Kotlin features.